# How to change weight unit for specific product category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

In my Magento website for food delivery all items are with weight - grams (gr).

But i have drink category where I want products there to show weight - milliliters (ml).

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add an attribute "Volume:"?

Even though you can show the weight to your customers, it really is there for a good purpose: Shipping Calculations!

To add an Attribute, go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` then click on "+ Add New Attribute"

Create all the options you might need: 375ml, 75cl, 1L etc

Then don't forget to add the attribute to the attribute set of the concerned product. got to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets` and click on Default or whichever set your product is using.

Hope it helps!